# why switch will expect statement before loading nib

Tags: iphone

In Switch statement

Example

```
switch (indexPath.row)
case 0:
Loading my nib file;
break;
case 1:
Loading another nib file;
break
default:
break
........
```

Before loading my nib file. It expects any one statement.

example

```
case 0:
NSLog(@"");
Loading Nib file....
```

My its expect the statement NSLog(@"");....... If i need not put NSLog... or any other statement its gives me error.....

I want to know why its like that.

Comment: definitely very confusing, I agree

Comment: What is your code that loads the nib files? Why are your switch statements missing the curly braces?

Comment: There was a previous question regarding this, but I can't find that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem that Objective-C inherited from C in a strange way. Basically the statements in each `case` have to be in a single block. The compiler figures this out when the statement immediately after the `case` statement isn't an assignment, but gets confused if it is.

You can solve it the way you did, with the `NSLog`, or you can simply surround your statements with curly braces to create a block:

```
case 0: {
    Loading my nib file;
    break; 
}
case 1: {
    Loading another nib file;
    break; 
}
```

Note that if you don't have an assignment (`x = y`) right after the `case` it won't be a problem. For example:

```
case 0:
    if (a = 1) NSLog(@"This works fine");
    break;
```

In the later example you gave you instantiated an object right after the `case` statement -- `TestiPhoneCalViewController *testiPhoneCalViewController` -- which wasn't an assignment, so it was fine.